# What should I do if I accidentally get graded on a take-home exam for someone else's work?

Tags: exams

A few weeks ago, I had an exam. Some of the questions were to be solved by computer and the results printed out and handed in. I didn't do well on the exam: I didn't solve some of the questions and I didn't do the part where I was supposed to print out the results, so I expected to get an F or D but I got a really good grade! Then i went to the professor's office to check my exam i was shocked to see that the papers that I was supposed to print out were "included" and solved correctly!

I was so shocked and nervous I didn't even say a word and left the office! I'm still shocked. I don't know what to do: I don't know if he really helped me or the papers weren't mine and by mistake got included with my papers! And now, when I see him around, I feel awkward. What am I supposed to do?

Shall i go back to his office and tell him i just want to check my grade and leave? Or that i need someone to explain what happened?

Comment: Tell him that you didn't do those parts and ask him to retake the exam. Also inform him that "your" exam is probably someone else's who may deserve a better grade than he/she got.

Comment: While this may be off-topic as a student question, it's very much on-topic for faculty who may have to deal with such a situation.

Answer (score 2):

Do go and see the professor, as pointed out someone else may be hurting. It may well be that the prof could turn around and sort the other person's grade to its correct value - if that is the case, and then say, well for your honesty, yours won't change...

However, do be prepared to retake it, or your grade to change...

It also depends on how many assessments there are in the course: if there are only a few it may be corrected, but if there are many - then it won't make a huge difference...

Be known for your attitude...

Answer (score 1):

You should go to your professor, explain what happened and your confusion with your score, and ask to retake the test if indeed this was in error.